# unable to drag and drop an webelement using selenium(java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

i am trying to drag an element(//li[text()=' Rel_ME_Hotfix ']) into destination webelement (//div[@id='dropEventDataId0']). below is the code i've tried.

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()=' Rel_ME_Hotfix ']"));
WebElement destination=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dropEventDataId0']"));       
act.clickAndHold(source).pause(2000).moveToElement(destination).release().build().perform();
```

also tried

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement From = driver.findElement(from);
WebElement To = driver.findElement(to);
action.dragAndDrop(From,To).build().perform();
```

tried with destination webelement as //div[@id='masterOptionDiv'] but no luck.

The script just runs through but the element doesnt get dropped into the destination web-element. attaching html code for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this worked by drag and drop using javascript.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver();
        js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" + "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n"
                            + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" + "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n"
                            + "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n"
                            + "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" + "return event;\n"
                            + "}\n" + "\n" + "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n"
                            + "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" + "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n"
                            + "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n"
                            + "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" + "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n"
                            + "}\n" + "\n" + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n"
                            + "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" + "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"
                            + "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n"
                            + "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n"
                            + "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n"
                            + "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" + "\n"
                            + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n"
                            + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", source, destination);   }
```